# Why MPI_Bcast is not working when cores >= 12 for a given input?

Tags: c, openmpi

I have the current code working for cores under 12, using prints, code works until MPI_Bcast(&global_mean,...) prints before it are shown and after no:
Note: MPI custom type has been created and has been tested;

```
int main (int argc, char ** argv)
{ 

    int pid, n_processors;
    const int ROOT = 0;

    int xsize, ysize, colmax;
    pixel *src = (pixel*) malloc(sizeof(pixel) * MAX_PIXELS);

    // Scatter receiver vector
    pixel *receive_buffer;

    int send_count, partial_sum, total_sum, global_mean, nump, remainder;

    double global_time = 0.0;

    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &pid);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &n_processors);

    if(pid == ROOT){

        /* Take care of the arguments */
        if (argc != 3)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s infile outfile\n", argv[0]);
            exit(1);
        }

        /* Read file */
        if(read_ppm (argv[1], &xsize, &ysize, &colmax, (char *) src) != 0)
            exit(1);

        if (colmax > 255)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Too large maximum color-component value\n");
            exit(1);
        }

        printf("Has read the image, calling filter\n");

        send_count = (xsize * ysize)/n_processors;
        nump = xsize * ysize; 


    }

    double start_time = MPI_Wtime();


    MPI_Bcast(&send_count, 1, MPI_INT, ROOT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);


    // Initialize receive_buffer
    receive_buffer = (pixel*)malloc(send_count * sizeof(pixel));

    // 1. Scatter src array through different proccessors
    MPI_Scatter(src, send_count, mpi_pixel_type, receive_buffer, send_count, mpi_pixel_type, ROOT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // 2. Do partial sums
    int i;
    partial_sum = 0; 
    for(i = 0; i < send_count; i++){
        partial_sum += (unsigned int)receive_buffer[i].r + (unsigned int)receive_buffer[i].g + (unsigned int)receive_buffer[i].b;
    }

    MPI_Reduce(&partial_sum, &total_sum, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, ROOT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    // Calculate missing pixels
    if(pid == ROOT){
        remainder = nump % n_processors;
        for(int i = nump - remainder; i < nump; i++)
            total_sum += (unsigned int)receive_buffer[i].r + (unsigned int)receive_buffer[i].g + (unsigned int)receive_buffer[i].b;
    }

    // 3. Calculate mean
    if(pid == ROOT)
        global_mean = total_sum/nump;




    MPI_Bcast(&global_mean, 1, MPI_INT, ROOT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    // 4. Apply algorithm 
    MPI_Scatter(src, send_count, mpi_pixel_type, receive_buffer, send_count, mpi_pixel_type, ROOT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
    unsigned int psum;
    for(i = 0; i < send_count; i++){
        psum = (unsigned int)receive_buffer[i].r + (unsigned int)receive_buffer[i].g + (uint)receive_buffer[i].b;
        if(global_mean > psum)
            receive_buffer[i].r = receive_buffer[i].g = receive_buffer[i].b = 0;
        else
            receive_buffer[i].r = receive_buffer[i].g = receive_buffer[i].b = 255;

    }

    // 5. Gather partial results
    MPI_Gather(receive_buffer, send_count, mpi_pixel_type, src, send_count, mpi_pixel_type, ROOT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if(pid == ROOT){
        // printf("Reamainder: %d\n", remainder);
        for(i = nump - remainder; i < nump; i++){
            psum = (unsigned int)src[i].r + (unsigned int)src[i].g + (uint)src[i].b;
            if(global_mean > psum)
                src[i].r = src[i].g = src[i].b = 0;
            else
                src[i].r = src[i].g = src[i].b = 255;

        }
    }


    double end_time = MPI_Wtime();

    global_time += end_time - start_time;

    if(pid == ROOT){
        printf("Filtering took: %g secs\n", global_time) ;

        /* Write result */
        printf("Writing output file\n\n");

        if (write_ppm(argv[2], xsize, ysize, (char *)src) != 0)
            exit(1);
    }




    MPI_Finalize();  

    return 0;

}
```

Under core < 12 is working fine but when cores >= 12

```
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   PID 56361 RUNNING AT sigma.nsc.liu.se
=   EXIT CODE: 11
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
```

Where did I do wrong in my code? Why stops working only when certain cores is reached?

Comment: `for(i = 0; i <= send_count; i++)` Not reading your code carefully, are you sure this is not off-by-one error?

Comment: Oh, didnt notice that. But even correcting that still showing the same error

Answer (score 0):

*Why stops working*...
Likely because your process is attempting to access memory it does not own, leading to the error:  `BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES`

Here you are creating memory for `send_count` pixels in `receive_buffer`:

```
receive_buffer = (pixel*)malloc(send_count * sizeof(pixel));
```

Then here, you are indexing one past the memory you have created:

```
for(i = 0; i <= send_count; i++){
             ^^
        psum = (unsigned int)receive_buffer[i].r + (unsigned int)receive_buffer[i].g + (uint)receive_buffer[i].b;
        if(global_mean > psum)
```

Change to

```
for(i = 0; i < send_count; i++){
             ^
```

Comment: But even correcting that still showing the same error :(

Comment: @YunhaoLin - Have you also looked at the difference `nump - remainder`?  (Can it ever be negative, thus causing `for(i = nump - remainder; i < nump; i++){` to create a negative index.)  Beyond that, stepping through the code in a debugger should tell you exactly where the fault occues.

Comment: Yes, always >= 0

Answer (score 0):

The error was caused because I was computing with receive buffer after MPI_Reduction and should have used src :)
Thanks all for your suggestions